# Having Trouble to select row in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Friend I've been trying to set default Checkmark in my UITableView Cell,Here is my code please look at this, I'm having serious trouble to get my desire output

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *cellIdent = @"cell1111";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
if (tableView==_ShapeSelectionTable)
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_ShapeSelectionTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    if([_selectedShapeArray containsObject:[_shapeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] || [_selectedShapeArray containsObject:@"Check All"]) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
  for (NSString *s in _shaperesultArray)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<self.shapeArray.count; i++)
        {
        NSIndexPath *myIdx=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
         ShapeInfo *shap=[self.shapeArray objectAtIndex:i];


            if ([shap.shape isEqualToString:s])
            {


                cell = [[self ShapeSelectionTable] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 //[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:myIdx animated:TRUE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
 }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }

        }
    }
 ShapeInfo *shap=[_shapeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=shap.shape;

    return cell;
}
```

I want to get following output From my ResultInfo is , Cell should remember accessory type [image]

Friends I'm having trouble with preCheckmark(Cell Accessory) from My JSON Objects 
Note I'm getting that Output from Web in JSON Format
Any Help will be appreciated ..Thanks

**UPDATE When I run this code Getting Exception Like 
   Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509
2014-06-24 14:14:24.306 TheGemHubApp[2405:60b] *** 
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> 2935.137/UITableView.m:6509 2014-06-24 14:14:24.306 TheGemHubApp[2405:60b] Terminating app 
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView 
>   dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'*

I guest this exception happen at this line of code

```
 cell = [[self ShapeSelectionTable] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

You should put some break point here and simulate what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out my mistake...but What would be suggestion ,Which Logic I should use to get my desire result? Any idea?

Comment: You should not use this function:
cell = [[self ShapeSelectionTable] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];


you should only config the delegate of UITableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath. And when you want to update tableview: you can simple call: 
[yourtable reloadData] 
or using row update command

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `-selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you don't have to select a row to show a check mark.

Comment: Hello @CarmeloS then How I can I achieve my desire output?

Comment: @NikunjKatharotiya you just set the cell.accessoryType, and it will show a check mark on your cell.

Comment: I want my Cell should get checked by my JSON data array which is in _shapeResultArray

Comment: Cell don't "remember" their state, instead you should configure the cell every time cell is displayed. I don't see anything wrong in your modified code, may I ask what do you mean by "cell get checked"?

Comment: While I'm trying to display my Record in UITextfield ,When I click on button Will display cell with checkmark as per my Code.  Hope you get my question

Comment: @NikunjKatharotiya I'm so sorry but I'm not sure what you mean.